# Outlook Add-In getAccessToken return error 13001 (No user is signed into Office.) on Chrome Incognito

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to implement SSO on an Outlook add-in.

```
OfficeRuntime.auth.getAccessToken({ allowConsentPrompt: true, allowSignInPrompt: true });
```

It works well on Chrome but not in Incognito mode where I get the following error:
Error 13001 (No user is signed into Office.)

From:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/troubleshoot-sso-in-office-add-ins

> This error is never seen in Office on the web. If the user's cookie
> expires, Office on the web returns error 13006.

I am definitely on Office on the web...

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue with getAccessToken. 
We have a few follow-up questions. 
1. Is pop-up enabled in the browser ? (This is required for signing the user in and consent)
2. Can you see the console for any error (if any)

Comment: 1. I don't think that popups are enabled by default on Chrome in normal and incognito mode. 2. No specific error outside 13006.

Comment: Can you please provide with the detailed repro steps ? We want to try this at our end once

Comment: 1. Create an Add-in with uses the getAccessToken function. 
2. Load the plugin on Outlook Web on Chrome Incognito

Comment: Can you please provide us the manifest which you are using for this scenario??

Comment: https://shrib.com/?v=nc#Zoie-3Q2o1m

Comment: We tried with the latest version on Outlook Web and we were not able to reproduce this issue. We only got the 13006 error as mentioned in the documentation. If you can identify a user condition or have a solid repro please feel free to comment here again and we will investigate the issue.